# How Android API get battery percentage?

Tags: android, battery, energy

I am researching about energy in Android. When I need to know the current charge state through percentage of Android system, I run the following function:

```
public float getBatteryLevel() {

    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f; 
}
```

But I don't know how Android API knows the current charge state of battery and yields the result? I researched around and know some battery measurement methods such as:

- Related between voltage and charge state:
  http://www.powerstream.com/lithium-ion-charge-voltage.htm
- Coulomb counting

Is Android API using any method above? Or another method?

Comment: AFAIK, Android isn't doing anything, other than asking the hardware. How the hardware reports this stuff, through ACPI or whatever, is up to the device manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is any document of any device manufacturer about how hardware report this stuff? I want to measure energy for more accuracy, android api always yield percentage in integer value, is any way to measure in more specific precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of three main ways for the OS to get the battery (and other power) information.

- [/proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) - these are files tied directly to various OS and hardware tables. When you access these files, you are actually querying the OS for the values of those tables. Unfortunately, it is very system dependent in that it depends upon the kernel implementation.
- [PAPI (Performance APIs)](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/performance-monitoring-with-papi/184406109) - these are meant to address the problem around there being a lack of standardization for get performance information. Though there is a Java implementation, I haven't found anything telling me there is an android implementation.
- [ACPI Tables](http://www.acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPIspec50.pdf) - Standardized OS tables for holding information. I've found them a little more platform dependent than I wanted.

Another way of accessing this information is directly from the hardware itself. As you can guess, this is very platform dependent. It varies from architecture to architecture, including even different versions of the same architecture.

One other note about the high-level APIs, such as PAPI, ACPI tables and /proc. They may or may not query the hardware even if the information is there. It all depends upon how the kernel and API developers did the implementation.